# Organizing various requests in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am a newbie in Node.js (and Express) and I am trying to make sense of this. Say I have a website with 3 pages (can be GET or POST): `/`, `/page1`, `/page2`. What should I do so that every page is handled by a separate JS file?

```
app.all('/', function(request, response)
{
    // Get home.js to handle this request and response
});
app.all('/page1', function(request, response)
{
    // Get page1.js to handle this request and response
});
app.all('/page2', function(request, response)
{
    // Get page2.js to handle this request and response
});
```

Better yet, is there a way to define a wildcard so there is not so much repetition? Something like this:

```
app.all('*', function(request, response)
{
    // Get *.js to handle this request and response. * is whatever the URI string is
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing my discussion with @Alex. Here's how I did it. Any gotcha?

```
// app.js
var EXPRESS = require('express');
var URL = require('url');
var PATH = require('path');

var app = EXPRESS.createServer();

app.all(/^\/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$/, function(request, response, next)
{
    var page = request.params[0];
    if (PATH.existsSync(__dirname + '/' + page + '.js'))
    {
        require('./' + page).handleRequest(request, response, next);
    }
    else
    {
        next();
    }
});

app.all('*', function(request, response)
{
    response.send('Catch all');
});

// --- truncated for brievity


// page1.js
exports.handleRequest = function(request, response, next)
{
    response.send('Howdy!');
};
```

Answer (score 4):

The trick here is that `app` is local to the file that creates it.  So you have to get that object to the scope of the other files.

Each other file should export a funciton that you can pass your app instance to so it can register new routes.  An approach like this should work.

```
// home.js
exports.register = function(app) {
  app.all('/', function(request, response) { ... });
};

// page1.js
exports.register = function(app) {
  app.all('/page1', function(request, response) { ... });
};

// page2.js
exports.register = function(app) {
  app.all('/page2', function(request, response) { ... });
};

//server.js - setup the app
app = express.createServer();
require('./home').register(app);
require('./page1').register(app);
require('./page2').register(app);
```

---

And for the second part of your question, you want to share some setup methods?

```
app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header 'x-snazzy-header', 'Im so snazzy'
  next()
});

app.all('/page/:id', function(req, res) {
  res.send('content for page #'+ req.params('id'));
});
```

First, you can use `*` or named params like `/users/:id`, to match a range of routes.  And if you want to do some common setup, you can actually execute 2 routes.  The route handler takes an optional third argument `next`.  When invoked, it will try to find the next route to match.  So you can setup things like common headers for a bunch of routes with it.

Comment: Thanks. Almost there, but not quite. How do I use your second example to route all incoming request to its corresponding file (using the request path as the filename)? My second question, basically.

Comment: You dont bind a request to a file, you execute code that registers a handler to a path pattern.  It doesn't really matter where that code is stored, only that you run it.  Thats an important idea to understand.  But that said, I'm not quite clear what you are asking...

Comment: Let me try again. Take your first example. The problem I see is: as you add more pages, you need to update `server.js` with new `require` per page. As your site grows larger, this could get very tedious. Can it be done more dynamically so that the URI of the request is used as the filename of the JS that is handling the request?

Comment: That's really not a good idea.  You should load all routes that you need as the server boots up.  You could use `fs` and `path` modules in node.js to find source files in a directory and and then `require()` and call `register()` each one dynamically in a loop.  Then all handlers are ready and waiting for any request your app can handle.